# Scrollview not displaying items

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I am trying to display a `UIView` on a `UIScrollView`, and the `UIView's` will display horizontally lined-up. However, only 1 Item appears in the `ScrollView` when I scroll it horizontally.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.scollV.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width * 10, height: 200)

    for i in 0..<10 {

            self.myview.frame.size.width = self.view.bounds.size.width
            self.myview.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(i) * self.view.bounds.size.width

            self.label.text = "\(i)"

            self.myview.addSubview(self.label)
            self.scollV.addSubview(self.myview)

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you just started programming in swift for ios, and there are so many basic errors in your code.
First things first.

1. You have only one `UIView` instance created, and you are adding it multiple times to the scroll view, that's why you have only 1 item on the scroll view. Create items (`UIView` instances) inside the cycle, and add them to the scroll view. (Really hope you know how to do it)
2. No need to add scroll view in the cycle, this is wrong, you should add it only once.
3. Read ios programming basics!